# Unique characterizing property of identity component

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups, topological-groups

Is there any characterizing property of path component of identity in a topological group? In other words, how will I show that some path connected subgroup is the identity path component of topological group?

Comment: There is no topological characterising property, since all connected components in a topological group are homeomorphic to each other (since $G$ acts on itself by left multiplication, and each multiplication is a homeomorphism). So only the extra data of how the group acts characterises this component.

Comment: @joppy thanks...

Comment: @Joppy You should give an official answer.